# UIAlertView:wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have already running `UIAlertView`, But during Getting data from Webservice i want to update Message of that AlertView. So I write below Code to update message of alert:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateAlertMessage:) withObject:@"Downloading Schedule ..." waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)UpdateAlertMessage:(NSString *)strMessage
{appDelegate.progressAlert.message=strMessage;
}
```

Here progress alert is my already running alertview.

But I give me below warning in Console:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

I want to remove that warning.
Any Help??

Comment: Where you're calling this method ??? in `viewWillAppear:` ???

Comment: i am calling this method during XML Parsing data i.e. - (void)elementFound:(const xmlChar *)localname prefix:(const xmlChar *)prefix uri:(const xmlChar *)URI namespaceCount:(int)namespaceCount

Comment: It is because there are two threads and you are trying to call the main thread and the main thread in turn calls another thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371346/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003

Comment: Set `waitUntilDone:YES` then see what happen ..

Comment: @TheTiger I tried with waitUntilDone:YES also but it give me still same warning.

Comment: @satheeshwaran Might be duplicacy here any other way to update alertview message during XML Parsing??

Comment: @TheTiger How can I use GCD?

Comment: Can you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193108/uialertview-wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it on Main thread so try to use GCD method instead of [self `performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(UpdateAlertMessage:) withObject:@"Downloading Schedule ..." waitUntilDone:NO];`

like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
  [self UpdateAlertMessage:@"Downloading Schedule ..."];
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue;
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
    [self UpdateAlertMessage:@"Downloading Schedule ..."];
});
```

Comment: I also try this but still it give same warning during running in iPad i.e. wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Comment: @Divya jain Please try updated answer. Try to create own queue and test

Comment: I tried with your updated answer and tested in iPad. But whenever that queue is executing still it give same warning. Did this warning crash the app?? or May I continue with this warning??

Comment: it is same : wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Comment: There must be something going in iterative loop.